# VMware tools not working 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vmware, vmware-tools

So I upgraded my distro from 12.10 to 14.04 and VMware tools now no longer works.

I've recompiled with the new 3.13 kernel, I've tried uninstalling and installing again, nothing seems to be working. I've even fixed vmhgfs.

Answer (score 12):

To install the VMWare Tools provided by VMWare as an iso:

Step 1: Install the build tools.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Step 2: Every time you update your kernel, install the headers:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Step 3: Install/Update the tools from the `vmware-tools-distrib` directory:

To Install:

```
sudo ./vmware-tools-install.pl
```

To Update:

```
sudo ./vmware-tools-config.pl
```

---

The newer VMWare Tools installers warns you in advance to try and find an `open-vm-tools` package if available.

To install `open-vm-tools` from the console, type in:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Restart the PC, log in and you're done!

However, there are some caveats, listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/270112/open-vm-tools-vs-vmware-tools).

Comment: The key here was to install open-vm-tools-desktop. It seems to be mandatory but is not dependency for some reason.

Comment: @LucaCarlon Indeed! All the guides I found (including the warning message shown by `vmware-tools-install.pl` script itself) talk about `open-vm-tools` but it's `open-vm-tools-desktop` which made the difference for me!

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, at some point Ubuntu switched to `open-vm-tools`, try this package instead of the old vmware tools. Those packages are based on the source code VMware released, but are open source.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in installing vmware-tools on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS using this guide:

http://packages.vmware.com/tools/docs/manuals/osp-esxi-51-install-guide.pdf